# Do Vedas say that devatas are mantra-baddha?

Tags: vedas, mantras, yajna, purva-mimamsa

[This site](http://hindupedia.com/en/Fundamentals_of_Mantra_Sadhana_or_Practice) says that

> Every devata is said to be mantra-baddha, that is, the devata is obliged to fulfill the purpose for which the mantra/devata is invoked.

Previously also I have come across this belief that devatas invoked in yajnas are bound to fulfill purpose of yajna if properly performed because they are bound by mantras. Which verses from Vedas(Samhita, Brahmana, Aranyaka, Upanishadas) support this belief that devatas are bound by mantras?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yes, purva mimamsa beliefs are one of the things which inspired this question. I am more interested in knowing if there are any direct vedic verses which say devatas are bound to mantras and bound to give results. Yes, you are right, it is possible in some of the mimamsa works linked to in answers of that question may have such direct vedic verses.